# Is there a way to stack boxes up as you might expect in the back of a truck?

Tags: objects, physics

I have a large number of box models (think UPS, DHL, Amazon) and I want to stack them up in the back of a truck like a human would. Is there any functionality in Blender that will allow me to do this?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could create a box, give it *Physics > Rigid Body > Active* type, duplicate, create a ground that is *Physics > Rigid Body > Passive* type:

[image]

Select all the boxes and *Object > Transform > Randomize Transform*:

[image]

In the *Operator* box, play with the parameters:

[image]

Play the animation, the box will fall and stack:

[image]

If you don't need anymore physics you can select all the boxes and *Object > Rigid Body > Bake to Keyframes*.

Comment: +1 for your red arrows, although the menu entries are already blue ;)

Comment: to say the truth I had to restrict myself not to add some more

Comment: so you are arrow addicted? :D

Comment: yes, I wanted to point each box but didn't find a solution to point the ones behind

Comment: you should have tried the wireframe mode :D I am happy, i could help :D

Comment: oh my god you're right I was so stupid

Comment: no not stupid, we are all learners :D Just ask me...if you want stupid answers :D

Comment: plus red arrows are not accurate, they should have been green, I hope my red arrow have not misled people these last 4 years, oh my god I need to edit all my answers, nooooooooooooooo

Comment: Now you now why you only got 3 upvotes, if they would have been green - you would have 100+ upvotes!!!! :D     You made my day. I am very very happy that people like you are here with a huge knowledge, always friendly, unbelievable helpful and lots of humor. Love that. Only met maximum of 3 people who met that criteria. Robin is another one. I would have left this forums months ago if you weren't here...too many people here who just want to play sheriff and think they know everything better  (puke)

Comment: but but but I'm very serious Chris, I'm offended you don't take me seriously  :/

Comment: @moonboots this is a great answer to my question. BUT, I realised I forgot a crucial point (and even my image doesn't illustrate it). The boxes are all different sizes and orientations (but they are still all cuboids). The challenge then becomes writing a script to arrange them in such a way that when they are dropped they stay stacked. It's a difficult mathematical problem, but I was hoping there would be some blender add-on or functionality that handles it.

Comment: what do you mean, in what way the fact that they have different sizes change anything? It just changes the creation of the rows at the beginning as you need to bring a bit of variety, but the randomize transform and physics will work fine. Please explain more in detail

Comment: @moonboots sure. It is indeed the creation of the rows bit that's challenging. With same size oriented boxes it's trivial to place them in a regular lattice. But with different size boxes (different heights lengths and widths) it's a little like Tetris trying to pack them together. If you just put them in a regular lattice, when you drop the lot, it will all just topple down. And even if it doesn't topple, you'll end up with weird looking totem poles. The actual mathematical problem of packing different shaped boxes is very hard, and I was hoping I wouldn't have to write my own script for it

Comment: just create 3 kind of rows, then Alt D to duplicate the rows, rotate them 180° on an axis, select the 2 rows, rotate them 180° on another axis, and so on, in few seconds you have tens of rows of boxes of different sizes

Comment: the Randomize Transform even allows you to give random sizes to your boxes, you could also play with some random textures

Comment: @AlexanderSoare if a real human can load that van full of random boxes in 10 minutes, so can you in Blender :)

Comment: @Cylindric yes but try generating 20k photorealistic images overnight with an RTX 3090 and 16 CPU cores ;)

Comment: Thanks for the tips @moonboots